# How can I save my object with values from an abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have class

```
@Data
public class ScreenshotInput extends InputModel implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final byte[] image;
  private final Timestamp timeCreated;

  public ScreenshotInput(byte[] image, String taskName, Timestamp timestamp) {
    super(taskName);
    this.image = image;
    this.timeCreated = timestamp;
  }
}
```

and my abstract InputModel class:

```
@Data
public abstract class InputModel {
  private String taskName;
  private String userName;

  public InputModel(String taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
    this.userName = Preferences.userRoot().get("username", "username");
  }
}
```

And when I want to save on stake created object ScreenshotInput, only values defined in ScreenshotInput class are saved to my object: image, and timestamp. Value taskname and username are available (f.e. when I want to print it before saving my object to the stake), but they are not in the object on the stake.
What can I do to have the variables from InputModel written to my object by default?

Comment: Have you tried setting the members in `InputModel` to `protected`?

Comment: InputModel implements Serializable

Comment: @jmizv yes, but I think it It does not matter which access modifier is set

Comment: Yes, just a fast guest. Can you try the proposal of @FLYFLU? And then showing the code how you serialize your object?